# TypeError: write() takes at least 5 arguments (2 given) - inherited module from v8 to v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm migrating some modules from v8 to v10 community

This time I have this error when trying to create an invoice:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 679, in call_kw
return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 664, in call_kw_model
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py", line 342, in create
invoice = super(AccountInvoice, self.with_context(mail_create_nolog=True)).create(vals)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 227, in create
thread = super(MailThread, self).create(values)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 3798, in create
record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 3958, in _create
self.recompute()
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 5277, in recompute
recs.browse(ids)._write(dict(vals))
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py", line 356, in _write
(reconciled & pre_reconciled).filtered(lambda invoice: invoice.state == 'open').action_invoice_paid()
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py", line 573, in action_invoice_paid
return to_pay_invoices.write({'state': 'paid'})
TypeError: write() takes at least 5 arguments (2 given)
```

It doesn't says where the actual error comes in, it must be from the module I'm migrating, this is the method which has `'state' : 'paid'` in my module:

```
@api.multi
def action_invoice_create(self, cr, uid, ids, wizard_brw, inv_brw,
                          context=None):
    """
    If the invoice has control number, this function is responsible for
    passing the bill to damaged paper
    @param wizard_brw: nothing for now
    @param inv_brw: damaged paper
    """
    invoice_line_obj = self.env('account.invoice.line')
    invoice_obj = self.env('account.invoice')
    acc_mv_obj = self.env('account.move')
    acc_mv_l_obj = self.env('account.move.line')
    tax_obj = self.env('account.invoice.tax')
    invoice = {}
    if inv_brw.nro_ctrl:
        invoice.update({
            'name': 'PAPELANULADO_NRO_CTRL_%s' % (
                inv_brw.nro_ctrl and inv_brw.nro_ctrl or ''),
            'state': 'paid',
            'tax_line': [],
        })
    else:
        raise osv.except_osv(
            _('Validation error!'),
            _("You can run this process just if the invoice have Control"
              " Number, please verify the invoice and try again."))
    invoice_obj.write(cr, uid, [inv_brw.id], invoice, context=context)
    for line in inv_brw.invoice_line:
        invoice_line_obj.write(
            cr, uid, [line.id],
            {'quantity': 0.0, 'invoice_line_tax_id': [],
             'price_unit': 0.0}, context=context)

    tax_ids = self.env('account.tax').search(cr, uid, [],
                                                  context=context)
    tax = tax_obj.search(cr, uid,
                         [('invoice_id', '=', inv_brw and inv_brw.id)],
                         context=context)
    if tax:
        tax_obj.write(cr, uid, tax[0], {'invoice_id': []}, context=context)
    tax_obj.create(cr, uid, {
        'name': 'SDCF',
        'tax_id': tax_ids and tax_ids[0],
        'amount': 0.00,
        'tax_amount': 0.00,
        'base': 0.00,
        'account_id': inv_brw.company_id.acc_id.id,
        'invoice_id': inv_brw and inv_brw.id}, {})
    move_id = inv_brw.move_id and inv_brw.move_id.id

    if move_id:
        acc_mv_obj.button_cancel(cr, uid, [inv_brw.move_id.id],
                                 context=context)
        acc_mv_obj.write(cr, uid, [inv_brw.move_id.id],
                         {'ref': 'Damanged Paper'}, context=context)
        acc_mv_l_obj.unlink(cr, uid,
                            [i.id for i in inv_brw.move_id.line_id])
    return inv_brw.id
```

Any ideas about this?

Since this is a code which operates on records, I've added the `@api.multi` decorator, but I'm not sure if this is the problem.

**EDIT**

This is the method on `account` module:

```
@api.multi
def action_invoice_paid(self):
    # lots of duplicate calls to action_invoice_paid, so we remove those already paid
    to_pay_invoices = self.filtered(lambda inv: inv.state != 'paid')
    if to_pay_invoices.filtered(lambda inv: inv.state != 'open'):
        raise UserError(_('Invoice must be validated in order to set it to register payemnt.'))
    if to_pay_invoices.filtered(lambda inv: not inv.reconciled):
        raise UserError(_('You cannot pay an invoice which is partially paid. You need to reconcile payment entries first.'))
    return to_pay_invoices.write({'state': 'paid'})
```

But I'm not sure if this is a bug, or the method from my module, which inherits `account.invoice` class is causing it, I think is the latter.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up old API with new API here:

```py
@api.multi
def action_invoice_create(
    self, cr, uid, ids, wizard_brw, inv_brw, context=None):
```

`cr`, `uid`, `ids` and `context` are handled by `self.env` so you don't need to declare them anymore. Odoo will wrap the method to old or new API style automatically, if it's needed.

New API style should be:

```py
@api.multi
def action_invoice_create(self, wizard_brw, inv_brw):
```

And one more hint for Odoo 10: It's `invoice_line_ids` now (finally) ;-)